# Star Crossword, and anagrams

Tags: anagram, crosswords

[image]

Rules:

- The star is from 5 straight lines, each line for 1 word.
- The 2 double circles have same letter.
- The 2 dashed circles have same letter.
- The direction is Top-Down. For horizontal line is Left-Right.
- Each number in anagram is the letter taken from the crossword.

Crossword clues:

- Mean "united" in Japanese
- Kingdoms.
- Different or unequal
- Things which are difficult to remove.
- An amount of money that is returned.

Solve These anagram, all have connection with “PUZZLE”:

- [11,12,14,16,17,18,20,3,6,10]
- [10,14,3,7,17]
- [16,7,17,11]
- [1,5,6,7,8,10,11,12,19,20]
- [2,3,4,6,11,12,18,19]

What is the 6-letters-word which describes the anagrams?
(The answer is not PUZZLE)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

United in Japanese

> subaru

Kingdoms

> realms

Different or unequal

> unlike

Things which are difficult to remove

> stains

An amount of money that is returned

> rebate

Yielding

> [image: solved star]

The rest was vastly aided by [ffao](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/20521/ffao) and (the now inactive) Hose Pipe.

`[11,12,14,16,17,18,20,3,6,10]`

> IKTTSUEANN -> [Ten Tsunaki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connect_the_dots)

`[10,14,3,7,17]`

> NTALS -> [Slant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gokigen_Naname)

`[16,7,17,11]`

> TLSI -> [LITS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LITS)

`[1,5,6,7,8,10,11,12,19,20]`

> RUNLMNIKBE -> [Numberlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numberlink)

`[2,3,4,6,11,12,18,19]`

> EARNIKUB -> [Nurikabe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nurikabe_(puzzle))

and the six letter word that describes the anagrams?

> [Nikoli](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikoli_(publisher)) - the publisher of the puzzles named above.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikoli_(publisher)

Comment: +1 The crossword is right. Slant and numberlink is right. others are still wrong.

Comment: EARNIKUB is Nurikabe, TLSI is LITS, and I'm not sure what IKTTSUEANN is; it's certainly not an anagram of anything I'm seeing on my numerous lists of Nikoli puzzles. My closest guess is BIJUTSUKAN, which is three letters away.

Comment: I must say, IKTTSUEANN contains a lot of different possibilities when splitted into two words: http://www.ssynth.co.uk/~gay/cgi-bin/nph-an?line=unitstaken&words=2&dict=antworth&doai=on

Comment: IKTTSUEANN is ten tsunaki; all answers were in the link I posted in my first comment

Comment: @ffao Thank you! I thought they would be when you posted the link but didn't find them. It looks like the final answerer left, so I'll update this. You obviously knew at least some of the names (which I didn't, although "number link" did stand out as something of this ilk).